# How can I get a value inside the select query using linq?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I have combined 2 tables Clients and Payments using LINQ inner join. After this, I fill in a new model Totals with a values from those two tables. I just need to get a `Username`. Any ideas? I'll be very thankful!

```
var results = from client in _db.Clients
                          join trade in _db.Payments on client.Id equals trade.ClientId
                          where (client.Id == trade.ClientId &&
                          DateTime.Compare(trade.TradeDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
                          DateTime.Compare(trade.TradeDate, (DateTime) toDate) <= 0)
                          select new { client.Username, trade};
            var cs = results
                .GroupBy(tr => tr.trade.ClientId)
                .Select(item => new Totals
                {
                    Username = //here I need to set a value
                    CommBcf = item.Sum(client => client.trade.CommBcf),
                    EcnAll = item.Sum(client => client.trade.EcnAll),
                    EcnRbt = item.Sum(client => client.trade.EcnRbt),
                    OpenGross = item.Sum(client => client.trade.OpenGross),
                    CloseGross = item.Sum(client => client.trade.CloseGross)
}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by key and name. You can group by mutiple columns by creating new anonymous object with `new {id,name}` .

```
 var results = from client in _db.Clients
                              join trade in _db.Payments on client.Id equals trade.ClientId
                              where (client.Id == trade.ClientId &&
                              DateTime.Compare(trade.TradeDate, (DateTime)fromDate) >= 0 &&
                              DateTime.Compare(trade.TradeDate, (DateTime) toDate) <= 0)
                              select new { client.Username, trade};
                var cs = results
                    .GroupBy(tr => new {id=tr.trade.ClientId,name=tr.trade.Name})
                    .Select(item => new Totals
                    {
                        Username = item.Key.name
                        CommBcf = item.Sum(client => client.trade.CommBcf),
                        EcnAll = item.Sum(client => client.trade.EcnAll),
                        EcnRbt = item.Sum(client => client.trade.EcnRbt),
                        OpenGross = item.Sum(client => client.trade.OpenGross),
                        CloseGross = item.Sum(client => client.trade.CloseGross)
    }).ToList();
```

Comment: It helped me a lot. My appreciation!

Comment: Please accept answer to show others it was helpful and that was answered.

Comment: Of course, but time limit isn't over for marking your reply as an answer;)

Comment: Oh yes, I remember , how invented those rules :)

Comment: Glad it help you :)

Comment: @LabLab But `item.Key.name` is `trade.Name` and not `client.Username`.

Comment: Idea is there. He figured it out. Just change: name=tr.trade.Name, with name=tr.clientUsername. And in prevously SELECT just write clientUsername=client.Username